# php explode identifying number at end of the line

Tags: php, explode

having issue with the explode, i have simple text file and each line is end with number. i just want to extract end of line number and create same number of sub stings. i tried to use explode function but unable to retrieve  only end of string number. following is .txt file structure and my code with expected result.

'text.txt'

a1 bbb ccc 111-111      ddd eee     3
a2 fff ccc (123-12312) 111-111      ddd eee     2
a3 bbb aaa (32 32)111-111       ddd eee     4

```
<?php  
    $file = "C:\\test.txt";  
    $f = fopen($file, "r");  
    while ( $line = fgets($f, 1000) ) {  
        print "<br/>";  
        $pieces = explode(" ", $line);  
        print $line;  
        print "<br/>";  
        print "<\t>";  
        for(i=0; i>=$pieces[5];i++)  
        {  
            print "<br/>";  
            print "<\t>";  
        }  
        print "<br/>";  
     }  
?
```

Output:
a1

1. sub string
2. sub string
3. sub string

a2
1. sub string
2. sub string

a3
 1. sub string
 2. sub string
 3. sub string
 4. sub string

Comment: i do not understand your output example. make it more exact pls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also just use [substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

`echo substr(trim($line), -1);`

Tho I would do it like:

```
<?php
$file = "./test.txt";

foreach(file($file) as $lines){
    echo '<ol>'.PHP_EOL;
    $i = 1;
    foreach($parts = explode(' ',trim($lines)) as $key=>$line){
        if($key == 0){echo "\t<p>".$line.'</p>'.PHP_EOL;}
        if($key >= 1 && $key <= end($parts)){echo  "\t<li>".$line.'</li>'.PHP_EOL;}
        $i++;
    }
    echo '</ol>'.PHP_EOL;
}
/* Result
<ol>
    <p>a1</p>
    <li>bbb</li>
    <li>ccc</li>
    <li>111-111</li>
</ol>
<ol>
    <p>a2</p>
    <li>fff</li>
    <li>ccc</li>
</ol>
<ol>
    <p>a3</p>
    <li>bbb</li>
    <li>aaa</li>
    <li>(32</li>
    <li>32)111-111</li>
</ol>

*/
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

The function you're looking for is called [end()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php)

> end() advances array's internal pointer to the last element, and
>   returns its value.

```
$pieces = explode(" ", $line);
echo end($pieces);
```